# Can I take a bazaar branch and make it my main shared repository?

Tags: bazaar

I have a bazaar repository on a shared server. I'd like to clean up the repo and set it up from scratch but maintain my history.  I don't know how the repository was created initially (is there a way to find out?).

- Can I take a branch and make that into my main shared repo?

Is this a viable process:

```
bzr init-repo --no-trees /home/bzr/myrepository
cd /home/bzr/myrepository
bzr init stable
cp /home/oldbzr/branch_taken_from_current_repo/* ./stable/
cp /home/oldbzr/branch_taken_from_current_repo/.bzr ./stable/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "branch" and a "repo" in Bazaar are totally separate concepts. You don't convert a branch into a repo. What you usually think of as a repo (in SVN or Git, for example) is actually a branch in Bazaar. What you want to do is create a new repo, then copy the old branch into the new repo.

You almost have it right, but you don't want to use "cp", you want to use "bzr branch". Note: You can usually use "cp" to copy branches *except* when you want Bazaar to move a branch into, out of, or across a repository -- then you need "bzr branch" to intelligently repack the history. So here is what you want to do:

```
bzr init-repo --no-trees /home/bzr/myrepository
cd /home/bzr/myrepository
bzr branch /home/oldbzr/branch_taken_from_current_repo stable
```

Note that I am not doing "bzr init" -- I don't want to create a new branch, just copy the old one. And I am not manually copying the old branch or its .bzr directory. If you copy the old branch's .bzr, it will not end up using the new repository. By doing a "bzr branch" it will go "oh hey, I am moving into a repository. Therefore, I will put all of my commit data into the shared repository, and just put a lightweight branch in 'stable'."

Answer (score 5):

You can use just plain branch into your shared repo as mgiuca suggested, but you also can convert your standalone branch to use shared repository. For that your steps should be extended with `bzr reconfigure` call:

```
bzr init-repo --no-trees /home/bzr/myrepository
cd /home/bzr/myrepository
bzr init stable
cp /home/oldbzr/branch_taken_from_current_repo/* ./stable/
cp /home/oldbzr/branch_taken_from_current_repo/.bzr ./stable/ 
cd stable
bzr reconfigure --use-shared
```

So, if we omit `cp` then you can create a shared repository "around" your branch:

```
cd /path/to/my/branch
bzr info                       # you should see you branch is standalone, 
                               # i.e. not using shared repo
bzr init-repo ../              # create shared repo in parent directory
bzr reconfigure --use-shared   # convert standalone branch to repository branch
bzr info                       # now you should see your branch is using shared repo
```